# Generating model file in LIBSVM

Tags: machine-learning, bioinformatics, libsvm

I am working on bioinformatics. I am having a data set of Amino Acid composition sequences.I want to classify these amino acid composition sequences in positive and negative class using SVM algorithm. I am using libsvm Tool for classification of amino acid sequences.Dataset which i have that contains 3909 rows. But when i am applying svm-train function of libsvm for generating the model file then the model file which is being generated contains 2233 row. So the actual dimension of my dataset is being reduced from 3909 to 2233. I am not getting that why this is happening..?? Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The model retains only the support vectors needed to define the classes.  Frankly, I'm surprised that it retained so many of the original rows.

Your terminology is not correct.  "Dimension" is the number of features (columns), not the number of rows.  The dimensionality has not been reduced.  One way to think of this is that it took 2233 of the observations to define the entire border between positive and negative.  The other 1694 points are "behind" other data points, farther from the border.

For a really simple example, consider all integers as the data points.  We classify them simply: all points larger than pi (3.14159...) are in the positive set; all smaller ones are marked negative.  Feed this to the SVM algorithm -- and what you get back is only *two* rows: 3 is negative; 4 is positive.  All other points are "behind" one or the other.

Does that help?